# jQuery Calculation Plugin: Summing subtotals to create grand total

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working with the [jQuery Calculation Plugin](http://www.pengoworks.com/workshop/jquery/calculation/calculation.plugin.htm) on a page where  I do quantity x price calculations that then add to a subtotal.  This is repeated 4 times.

Each set of 4 involve fields with different ids and differing calculations (more than just price x qty).

The id's of the 4 subtotal fields are subtotal_events, subtotal_raffle, subtotal_sdc, subtotal_late.

In addition to displaying the individual subtotals, I need to display a "grand total"...a total of the subtotals.

In the fiddle referenced below, I've hard-coded the values of two of the 4 subtotals.

I've also created a function recalc3, which is currently producing the NaN in the #grandtotal span.  The value should be $70 based upon the hard-coded subtotals, even if no tours or extra tickets are ordered.

Hours of reading posts and trial and error aren't getting me any closer, so any help with achieving the goal is very much appreciated.

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sadiem/7spHt/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to extract the text in SPAN element, but are using the $(this).val function.
Use $(this).text function and also remove the $ symbol in the text before parsing as float.

Updated  jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7spHt/9/

```
$("[id^=subtotal_]").each(function() {
  var fee = parseFloat($(this).text().replace("$", ""));
  grandtotal += fee;
});
```

Comment: Thanks, that helped! If you can spare time for another look, can you tell me why I can't get the Total Due (#grandtotal) to update except on keyup in the Events Section?  I need it to update everytime ANY of the 4 subtotals change, but I'm missing something.  (I would be grateful for any thoughts on how the calculation structure could have been more streamlined, though that is not necessary.  Thanks for helping me learn.
jsFiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/sadiem/crz2M/9/

Comment: That's because you are binding the keyup event to calcualte the grand total...The change event for [id^=subtotal_] will neven be fires since there is no such event as change for a SPAN element.

Comment: If you can summarize what you are trying to achieve, I can try to see  if there is a better implementation..

Comment: The Total Due needs to update anytime any of the 4 individual subtotals changes. (And the individual subtotals need to update anytime the fields that calculate *them* change, which I think is on keyup). So do I need to make those individual subtotals input fields instead of spans?

Comment: How/When are the individual sub totals changed? Are they (the span elements) updated via code or should the user be able to enter values?

Comment: The subtotal_events should change as the viewer enters the number of tickets they want for a tour (Entering that number results in a calculation of the cost for that event.  So 2 @ $40 would equal $80 the event total.  The event totals add up to the events subtotal.    The subtotal_raffle changes whenever #totaltickets changes (and IT changes whenever the viewer enters the number of adult/jr tickets they want.)  The subtotal_sdc changes when the viewer enters the number of tickets @$35 they want.  It is a directly calculated total, not a sum of somethng.

Comment: The subtotal_late...will probably be via direct viewer entry.

Comment: To explicitly answer one of your questions:  All but subtotal_late are calculated subtotals.  Subtotal_late is user-entered, but I can make it be if that is necessary.

Comment: Thanks to you, Cybernate, for putting me on the right path. See the latest http://jsfiddle.net/sadiem/crz2M/15/ where it working the way I wanted.  I know there has to be a more efficient way in the code and am happy for suggestions, but for now, it's working.

Comment: @Sadie : Glad you were able to figur it out. Will try to post an updated version (if needed) tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

You can also group your input in a class

eg.

```
input=price, class="price_inputs"
```

then

```
$j(".price_inputs").keyup(function()
  //Do calculations here
});
```

or in my case I had multiple classes because I had subtotals so I strung the classes together in a grandtotal calculation

```
$j(".inclassA,.inclassB,.inclassC").keyup(function()  //watches all the input classes
  //Get the subtotals from the various input class(groups) and add them together here
});
```

for using ids just replace .  with # ala CSS

also for NaN gotcha.  10 + 10 = 1010, 10*1 + 10*1 = 20, 0 = nil(Nan) 0*1=0